# Degree of order n of a graph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'd like to calculate the number of adjacent edges in an extra step of the `degree()` function. This would be a `degree()` of order 2, for example.
[image]

For example, the graph on the left illustrates the classic `degree()` function, but I'm looking for an additional level of `degree()` (graph on the right). The `degree()` of vertex "1" corresponds to 2 but the additional level is 5. Is there a way of calculating this degree of order n for each vertex?

Code:
`g1 <- graph(edges=c(1,2,1,3,2,3,3,5,2,4,4,5,5,6,4,6,4,7,6,7),n=7,directed=F)`
`plot(g1)`

Comment: Could you provide the code of your example network? It would be easier for others to help you in turn.

Comment: Yes, it's done.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You ask about counting edges, but the answer that you accepted counts vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try `ego`

```
> ego(g1, 2)
[[1]]
+ 5/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
+ 7/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 2 1 3 4 5 6 7

[[3]]
+ 6/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 3 1 2 5 4 6

[[4]]
+ 7/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 4 2 5 6 7 1 3

[[5]]
+ 7/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 5 3 4 6 1 2 7

[[6]]
+ 6/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 6 4 5 7 2 3

[[7]]
+ 5/7 vertices, from 47df27b:
[1] 7 4 6 2 5
```

or `ego_size`

```
> ego_size(g1,2)
[1] 5 7 6 7 7 6 5
```